# Microsoft Mathematics 4.0 does not respect window snapping

Tags: aero-snap

Sometimes when Microsoft Mathematics 4.0 is aero snapped it will jump some hundred pixels from its original location and resize itself when minimized. Is this just Microsoft not respecting their own OS or something I can fix?

Issue has occurred on multiple computers with multiple versions of Windows, currently Windows 10 Pro x64 Version 10.0.10240 Build 10240, Mathematics 4.0.1108.0000.

Comment: This sounds like an application bug.  While Windows 10 has the capability to run any Win32 software, if that application works or not, entirely depends on the application itself.  Most application incompatibilities with Windows 10, are not because of changes that happen with Windows 10, but because of Windows version specific work around that programmer use and end up breaking because of those improvements or changes in later versions of Windows.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like Microsoft. The program WAS last updated in 2011.

Comment: Your upset that Microsoft doesn't support a discontinued product?

Comment: Heh, mostly that they discontinued it in the first place. It's incredibly useful.